# onload not called from span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a very beginner error with my code. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf8' />
        <script type = 'text/javascript' src="scriptFirst.js"></script>
</head>
    <header>
        <span onLoad='textChange()' id='title' class='welcome'>

        </span>
        <nav class='welcome'>
        </nav>
        <br>
        <div id = 'firstDiv'>
        </div>
    </header>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript, of the name scriptFirst.js, which is in the same folder as the html.

```
function textChange(){
var title = document.getElementById("title");
title.innerHTML = "hello";
alert('hello')
}
```

unfortunately, running this code in a browser gives me a blank screen.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. `getElementByTagName` and `getElementByClassName` don’t exist.

Comment: Do headers really have `onload` events? I'm doubtful

Comment: @CertainPerformance I changed it

Comment: `onload` attributes don't work like that, not for headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the onload in a body element, and wrap your  element in it.

`<body onload="myFunction()"> your code here ... </body>`

```js
function textChange(){
var title = document.getElementById("title");
title.innerHTML = "hello";
alert('hello')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf8' />
</head>
<body onload='textChange()'> 
<header>
        <span id='title' class='welcome'>

        </span>
        <nav class='welcome'>
        </nav>
        <br>
        <div id = 'firstDiv'>
        </div>
  </header>
  </body>
</html>
```